# jQuery .on() not firing

Tags: jquery

I'm using the bootstrap dropdown list, to which I add new items dynamically. But, the `on()` event is not being fired for dynamically added items. Why ?

```
$('div.my-modal .some-class label.link').off();
$('div.my-modal .some-class label.link').on('click',function () {
     console.log('a');
});

...
$('div.my-modal .some-class').append("<li><label class='link'>test</label></li>");
```

Comment: as far as `.on()` knows all the elements are already created.  `.on()` won't be fired until the event handler needs to be launched or the page reloads - unless you bind it to something that changes like document (as alessandro minoccheri said)

Answer (score 3):

you can use method `.on()` with document to bind the event instead directly to the class because the instance doesn't exist already 
try this:

```
$(document).on('click','div.my-modal .some-class label.link', function () {
     console.log('a');
});
```

Comment: yeah, it works. Tell me, do I have to use .off() before .on() method in this case ? The page which contains that code can be loaded many times and I want to prevent event bubbling

Comment: .off() need  to be used when you want that .on() doesn't fire for example to disable a button event. in this case I think that isn't necessary, is like the old unbind() event @Tony